# nsis installer removes existing app links in start menu subdirectory

Tags: electron, nsis, electron-builder

I'm using [`electron-builder`](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder) to build an NSIS installer for our Electron app.

We have multiple applications all added to the start menu under a `Company Name` directory. On first install everything works as expected but on upgrade/reinstall the installer is removing all the other app shortcuts from the the subdirectory. Using [these steps](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/2381#issuecomment-352611654) its easily reproducable.

I think it might be something to do with this [`cleanupOldMenuDirectory`](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/blob/99c1025cdeff9636182c50f26b7918217e50fe81/packages/electron-builder-lib/templates/nsis/include/installer.nsh#L170) macro but I don't know enough about NSIS scripts to work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about electron-builder but I do know that `RMDir` in NSIS will only delete empty directories and `RMDir /r` will delete a directory and everything in it.

[The change](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/commit/df13706e43e6817d25fc846a65c2e4a765e2f924) on January 2nd should have fixed it as far as I can tell.

One way to find out if this macro is the culprit is to modify your electron-builder installation and add a `MessageBox MB_OK "Hello"` line to the start **and** end of the `cleanupOldMenuDirectory` macro. If the other shortcuts exists when the first MessageBox is displayed and they are gone when the 2nd MessageBox is displayed then you know where the issue is.

Comment: Thanks, for your help. I've finally found the culprit: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/blob/99c1025cdeff9636182c50f26b7918217e50fe81/packages/electron-builder-lib/templates/nsis/uninstaller.nsh#L45